# Non-Alphabetical characters

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a t-sql script that is extracting the members of our site, but I am having trouble with users who have used *, & or numbers in there business name.

I have the following data for example:

```
''Dream A Little Dream''
***Unique Business Card/Sign/Logo Designs***
3D Visual Creations
50dollarbanner.com
etc..
```

I have the letters of the alphabet along the top of the page and users can click "A" for example and it lists all the users starting with "A" is there a way to maybe make another for "0" for example and it will list all members starting with numbers or strange characters:

Here is my test script:

```
DECLARE @TotalPages INT
DECLARE @UserName varchar(50)
DECLARE @PG INT
DECLARE @PageSize INT
SET @UserName = 'Z'
SET @PG = 1
SET @PageSize = 70
BEGIN
    SELECT @TotalPages = COUNT(*)/@PageSize
    FROM Member
    WHERE (sbuser.sf_GetDisplayName(FirstName, LastName, BusinessName, DisplayNameTypeID) LIKE @UserName + '%')
    AND UserName IS NOT NULL;

    WITH FindSBMembers AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Claimed DESC, sbuser.sf_MemberHasAvatar(MemberID) DESC) AS RowNum,
        MemberID,                                                -- 1
        UserName,                                                -- 2
        PrCity,                                                  -- 3
        PrStateID,                                               -- 4
        sbuser.sf_MemberHasImages(MemberID) AS MemberHasImages,  -- 5
        sbuser.sf_MemberHasVideo(MemberID) AS MemberHasVideo,    -- 6
        sbuser.sf_MemberHasAudio(MemberID) AS MemberHasAudio,    -- 7
        sbuser.sf_GetDisplayName(FirstName, LastName, BusinessName, DisplayNameTypeID) AS DisplayName,          -- 8
        ProfileTypeID,                                           -- 9
        Zip,                                                   -- 10
        PhoneNbr,                                                -- 11
        PrPhone,                                                 -- 12
        Claimed,                                                 -- 13
        @TotalPages AS TotalPages,                               -- 14
        City                                                     -- 15
        FROM Member
        WHERE (sbuser.sf_GetDisplayName(FirstName, LastName, BusinessName, DisplayNameTypeID) LIKE @UserName + '%')
        AND UserName IS NOT NULL
        -- AND MemberID <> @MemberID
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM FindSBMembers
    WHERE RowNum BETWEEN (@PG - 1) * @PageSize AND @PG * @PageSize
    ORDER BY Claimed DESC
END
```

Here are details of an included script:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [sbuser].[sf_GetDisplayName](
@FirstName varchar(50),
@LastName varchar(50),
@BusinessName varchar(50),
@DisplayNameTypeID int)
RETURNS varchar(150) WITH schemabinding

AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @OUT varchar(150)
SET @OUT = ''
SET @FirstName = UPPER(LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(@FirstName)), 1)) + RIGHT(LTRIM(RTRIM(@FirstName)), LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@FirstName))) - 1)
SET @LastName = UPPER(LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(@LastName)), 1)) + RIGHT(LTRIM(RTRIM(@LastName)), LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@LastName))) - 1)
SET @BusinessName = UPPER(LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(@BusinessName)), 1)) + RIGHT(LTRIM(RTRIM(@BusinessName)), LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@BusinessName))) - 1)
IF @DisplayNameTypeID = 2   -- FIRST / LAST NAME
    BEGIN
        SET @OUT = @LastName + ', ' + @FirstName
    END
IF @DisplayNameTypeID = 3 -- FIRST NAME / LAST INITIAL
    BEGIN
        SET @OUT = @FirstName + ' ' + LEFT(@LastName,1) + '.'
    END
IF @DisplayNameTypeID = 4 -- BUSINESS NAME
    BEGIN
        SET @OUT = @BusinessName + ''
    END
RETURN @OUT
END
```

Many thanks for your help.

Regards,
Paul

Comment: It would help to know what the exact problem you are having is. I could guess that '&' is causing HTML rendering issues (use '&amp;') and that '*' is interfering with the 'LIKE' clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include all the entries with non-alphabetical startcharacters provided that the input parameter @UserName is '0', then you could try something like the WHERE Clause below (not tested)?

This would allow you to have a "Misc" category which you can retrieve by calling the procedure with @UserName = '0'

```
 WHERE (     
            (  sbuser.sf_GetDisplayName(FirstName, LastName, BusinessName, 
                                  DisplayNameTypeID) LIKE @UserName + '%'
            )         
         OR
            (
               PatIndex(‘[^A-Za-z]%‘,
                  sbuser.sf_GetDisplayName(FirstName, LastName, BusinessName, 
                                           DisplayNameTypeID)  > 0  ) 
               AND 
               @UserName = '0'
            )         
       )
       AND UserName IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this in the beginning (before the query, that uses `@UserName`):

```
IF @UserName = '0' SET @UserName = '[^a-z]';
```

If your collation is case-sensitive, then maybe you should use `'[^A-Za-z]'` instead.